# How to deploy multiple contracts with Truffle

Tags: javascript, blockchain, solidity, truffle

I trying to deploy multiple contracts in Truffle to learn how it works.

This is the code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity 0.8.11;

contract first{

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public totalSupply;

    mapping(address=>uint) public balances;

    function setAll(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint _totalSupply)public virtual{
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        totalSupply = _totalSupply;
    }

    function mint()public{
        balances[tx.origin] += 1;
        totalSupply -= 1;
    }

}


contract second {

    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint public totalAmount;

    address public _first;

    constructor(address fiirst){
        _first = fiirst;
    }

    function set(string memory _name, string memory _symbol, uint _totalAmount)public{
        first _fir = first(address(_first));
        _fir.setAll(_name, _symbol, _totalAmount);
        _fir.mint();
        _totalAmount -= 1;
        name = _name;
        symbol = _symbol;
        totalAmount =_totalAmount;
    }
}
```

This is deploy_contracts.js:

```
const first = artifacts.require("first");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(first, "BABACOIN", "BAB", 3000);
};


const second = artifacts.require("second");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  const addContract = first.address;
  deployer.deploy(second, addContract);
};
```

How can I pass the address of the first contract to deploy the second one?

I tried `first.address` but get an error.

Once I deploy the contract, how can I set a different Ganache address to interact with the contract in Truffle console?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]". It's important to use proper grammar on Stack Overflow; It's not a discussion board, it's more like a text book. Also, when asking about an error you're getting, you need to show us sufficient code to run and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using:

```
const first = artifacts.require("first");

const second = artifacts.require("second");


module.exports = async function (deployer) {

 await deployer.deploy(first, "BABACOIN", "BAB", 3000);

 await deployer.deploy(second, first.address);

};
```

Below statements are taken from [MDN Web Docs - Making asynchronous programming easier with async and await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await).

Here, the `async` keyword is added to functions to tell them to return a promise rather than directly returning the value.

You can read about promise here - [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

`await` can be put in front of any async promise-based function to pause your code on that line until the promise fulfills, then return the resulting value.

This is why the code works now.

Comment: It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.

Comment: @theTinMan i really don't understand what you mean...i think it's clear what i was looking for...